# Excel VBA Deleting Last added Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a excel questionnaire where user can add upto 5 answers (Minimum 1 answer and Max 5). My Add additional answer button works fine. However, I cannot make my delete button work. Appreciate any suggestions

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    If realPropertyBoxCount = 1 Then 
      '~~>counter for the number of answers

         MsgBox "Must enter at least one item"
         Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Set your range
        If realPropertyBoxCount = 2 Then
        Set rng = .Range("A14:G22")
            ElseIf realPropertyBoxCount = 3 Then
        Set rng = .Range("A23:G31")
            ElseIf realPropertyBoxCount = 4 Then
        Set rng = .Range("A32:G40")
            ElseIf realPropertyBoxCount = 5 Then
        Set rng = .Range("A41:G49")

        rng.Delete

        '~~> Insert the range
        rng.Offset(9).Insert Shift:=xlUp

        '~~> Clear the clipboard. More importantly remove the
        '~~> ant like borders
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If

     End With

     realPropertyBoxCount = realPropertyBoxCount - 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Once you delete a range - `rng.Delete` - you can't still refer to it, so `rng.Offset(9).Insert Shift:=xlUp` will fail.

Comment: Would you like to insert an entire row, down 9 rows away from `rng.Row`? If yes, you can firstly make the insertion and only then delete the range. Like @BigBen explained, the reference to `rng` is lost after its deletion. But think if you also want to count the existing `rng` row in that 9...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I decided to start over and use delete after offset function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with a friend to solve this deletion issue. It works as intended now but it does not save the "box count" (i.e. realPropertyBoxCount) after closing document. What I mean by this is if I add 5 boxes then try to add another box it will stop with a msgbox. But if I save the document and open it again then it will let me add 5 boxes as the count is set back to 0. Any ideas for a method to save the "boxcount" (realPropertyBoxCount)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    If realPropertyBoxCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Must enter at least one item"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim deleteOffset As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    deleteOffset = 4 + realPropertyBoxCount * 9

    For i = 1 To 9
        Rows(deleteOffset).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

    realPropertyBoxCount = realPropertyBoxCount - 1

End Sub
```